# delete not working in yes button of jquery popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

i created a popup with ok and cancel buttons for alert message before row delete in gridview using jquery but unable to delete when i press on ok button. Below is code i used, please help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        <!-- Load -->
    $(function () {
        $("#message").html("Are you sure you want to delete User?");
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "Delete Confirmation",
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {

                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            modal: true,
            visibility: hidden

        });
    });
    //<!-- Log Message Popup -->
    function UserDel() {
        $("#message").html("Are you sure you want to delete User?");
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "Delete Confirmation",
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                      return true;
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    return false;
                }
            },
            modal: true
        });
    }

  </script>
```

Comment: Try `OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete User?');"`

Comment: its working fine when i use return confirm(); but we get browser URL in that confirm message so i thought to go with jquery popup

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Let's say instead of using onclick you identify the deletable rows by the class deletable row

```
<tr class="deletablerow">blah blah</tr>
```

Then your js code would read:

```
$(function () {
      $('.deletablerow').on('click',function() {
        UserDel(jQuery(this));
      });

      function UserDel(element) {
        $("#message").html("Are you sure you want to delete User?");
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "Delete Confirmation",
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    element.remove();
                    return true;
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    return false;
                }
            },
            modal: true
        });
    } 
});
```

Comment: i'm calling my delete method DeleteUserRowClick() in onClick="DeleteUserRowClick"

how can i call in ok button

Answer (score 0):

The following link might be helpful for you

http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/572571/How-to-fire-button-click-event-from-jQuery-Popup-when-Page-loads/

Comment: simply page is refreshing but unable to delete row